# Jackson ObjectMapper: readValue returns null

Tags: java, jackson

I need to parse this json:

```
{
   "id":"cpd4-b39c4b2a-b5cb-4581-b519-6034aaa7fe4e",
   "transactionId":"768a9be4-b5b3-452f-9bd3-9fff2e9ace5c",
   "status":"PUBLIC",
   "confidential":true,
   "expiringAt":1231231,
   "locked":true,
   "metadata":[
      {
         "user":"admin",
         "creationTimestamp":1538578453285,
         "value":"metadata"
      }
   ],
   "security":"read",
   "timestampCreation":1538578453285,
   "userCreation":"admin",
   "appCreation":"app",
   "document":{
      "id":null,
      "transactionId":"768a9be4-b5b3-452f-9bd3-9fff2e9ace5c",
      "docId":"68aab3799a9380fe82ed43ff2d46a5b07da1b270-1282",
      "size":1282,
      "name":"pom.xml",
      "alias":"alias",
      "hash":"68aab3799a9380fe82ed43ff2d46a5b07da1b270",
      "title":"title",
      "encoding":"UTF-8",
      "mimeType":"application/xml"
   }
}
```

to a object `Reference` class:

```
public class Reference {

    private String id;
    private String transactionId;

    private DocumentStatus status;
    private Boolean confidential;
    private Integer expiringAt;
    private Boolean locked;

    private List<Metadata> metadata;
    private String security;

    // IDReferenciaAlta
    private Date timestampCreation;
    private String userCreation;
    private String appCreation;

    private Date timestampModified;
    private String userModified;
    private String appModified;

    private Date timestampDeletion;
    private String userDeletion;
    private String appDeletion;

    //getters and setters...
}
```

where `Metadata` is:

```
public class Metadata {

    private String user;
    private Date creationTimestamp;
    private String value;

    //getters an setters
}
```

Currently, I'm using this code:

```
Reference reference = null;
try {
    reference = this.mapper.readValue(jsonDocument, Reference.class);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO: Throw domain exception...
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is that `this.mapper.readValue(...)` returns `null`.

I know that json schema and `Reference` class propoerties are not exactly the same, but I expected to get a reference with "common" json properties

Comment: What about the `document` node ?

Comment: Please share the stack trace

Comment: If you want to ignore **document** data then, try to add **@JsonIgnoreProperties({"document"})** on your **Reference** class

Comment: what is DocumentStatus  in -> private DocumentStatus status;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the stack trace, we are almost clueless on what the error is. However, from what can be seen in this question, the `document` property in not mapped to any field of the `Reference` class.

So you can either:

- Map the `document` property to a field.
- Use [`@JsonIgnoreProperties("document")`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) in the `Reference` class to ignore the `document` property. Alternatively you can use [`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) to ignore any unknown properties.
- Configure your [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) to ignore unknown properties by disabling [`DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES). See below:

  ```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
  Reference reference = mapper.readValue(jsonDocument, Reference.class);
  ```