# Returned null values when parsing JSON data from URL using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to retrieve some data from this url: https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/qs-rankings-data/397863.txt.

Here is the snippets of the url:

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "nid": "294850",
      "url": "/universities/massachusetts-institute-technology-mit",
      "title": "Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT)",
      "logo": "<img src=\"https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/massachusetts-institute-of-technology-mit_410_small_0.jpg\" alt=\"Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT) Logo\">",
      "core_id": "410",
      "score": "100",
      "rank_display": "1",
      "country": "United States",
      "region": "North America",
      "stars": "",
      "guide": "<a href=\"/where-to-study/north-america/united-states/guide\" class=\"guide-link\" target=\"_blank\">United States</a>"
    },
    {
      "nid": "297282",
      "url": "/universities/stanford-university",
      "title": "Stanford University",
      "logo": "<img src=\"https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/stanford-university_573_small_0.jpg\" alt=\"Stanford University Logo\">",
      "core_id": "573",
      "score": "98.6",
      "rank_display": "2",
      "country": "United States",
      "region": "North America",
      "stars": "",
      "guide": "<a href=\"/where-to-study/north-america/united-states/guide\" class=\"guide-link\" target=\"_blank\">United States</a>"
    }, (continue until the end....)
```

I'm only interested in retrieving the "Title" and "Country" but my codes returned `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I try to read the value.

Here is my Java code in main method:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        try {
            System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.29 Safari/537.36");
            UniversityList list = mapper.readValue(new URL("https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/qs-rankings-data/397863.txt"), UniversityList.class);

            for(University u : list.getUniversity()) {
                // Printing below, gives me null values
                System.out.println("Title: " + u.getTitle());
                System.out.println("Country: " + u.getCountry());
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And this is the DTO class:

```
class UniversityList{
    private List<University> university;

    public List<University> getUniversity() {
        return university;
    }

    public void setUniversity(List<University> university) {
        this.university = university;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UniversityList [university=" + university + "]";
    }
}

class University{

    private String title;
    private String country;

    public University() {
    }

    public University(String title, String country) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "University [title=" + title + ", country=" + country + "]";
    }
```

How do I get the "Title" and "Country" values? I'm not sure why it returned the null values. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Title (returned null) not exactly reflects essential NullPointerException. You should [edit] and describe the actual issue (e.g. marking code position with a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Jackson maps properties by name**!

[Some Java Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61277816/returned-null-values-when-parsing-json-data-from-url-using-jackson/61277944#61277944)'s advice would solve the issue by adjusting the name of nested *ArrayList* from `university` to `data` (same like corresponding array in JSON).

`java.lang.NullPointerException` (NPE) is thrown, when you try to get the list from your root object.

#### Issue: What happened?

**1. Tolerant reader pattern:**

You disabled [`DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
This tells Jackson to deserialize a *valid JSON* into an object, even if some of its contents can not be mapped.

Without disabling that (default setting) Jackson would have thrown an exception (`JsonMappingException`) here, since JSON property `data` could not be mapped to any of the properties of class `UniversityList`.

**2. No properties were mapped, all stay `null`:**

The object `list` was created (using *default* / *no-args* constructor). But since its property `ArrayList university` was neither initialized, nor set (mapped) by Jackson, it stays `null`.

**3. NPE thrown when accessing:**

As soon as your *for* loop tries to access the property via `list.getUniversity()` a NPE is thrown.

#### Prevention of NPE: Defensive coding

Always make sure that an object (reference) you are using is *not null*, here by:

```java
if (list != null && list.getUniversity() != null) {
  // now below for loop is safe (no NPE)
  for (University u : list.getUniversity()) {
      // do something with u
  }
}
```

Additionally it's usually good practice to initialize lists, even if they're empty. For example in your class `UniversityList` declare:

```
List<University> university = new ArrayList<>();
```

#### Handle with care: Jackson Features

Although the used `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` will act as a **Joker** here, allowing Jackson to read the JSON even if mapping does not fit, you should pay extra attention and **check return values**. See similar question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52647349

#### Define Jackson Mapping

Either use Jackson's default **mapping by name**: Java Object's property name must be **same** like in JSON.
Or use annotations `@JsonProperty` to define the *JSON name* if it **deviates** from Java Object name.

In your case this would be:

```java
@JsonProperty("data")
List<University> university = new ArrayList<>();
```

#### Customizing Jackson

Jackson offers many annotations that allow customization. See [Baeldung's Article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations).

So you can replace the globally disabled `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` by a class specific annotation as well:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UniversityList {
  // body removed
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for write-up! I got one more thing to clarify. So, if I'd like to use List<University> university, I just need to add the jsonproperty annotation to it, something like @jsonproperty("data") List<University> university, am I correct?

Comment: @Leomord Exactly! Well researched  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect if you changed the name of

```
private List<University> university;

public List<University> getUniversity() {
    return university;
}

public void setUniversity(List<University> university) {
    this.university = university;
}
```

to something more like

```
private List<University> data;

public List<University> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<University> data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

it would populate.  There are annotations you could use as well to tell Jackson "hey 'data' means my university list" - :).

Comment: Thanks. Changing the variable name fixed the problem. But I still don't know why is that causing the nullexception. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Assuming you are asking why title and country were null, it is because Jackson is trying to be smart.  It first tries to automatically map to members of the UniversityList.class by the actual member name. For example, in the json 'data' was mapped to 'private List<University> data;' quite literally by name.  So when jackson did not find a root element in the json with the name 'universityList' as in your first example, it threw an NPE.